# Unexpected redirection from TranslateThis button to google translate engine

Tags: redirect, google-translate, machine-translation

I am using TranslateThis (http://translateth.is/), a well-known API to translate webpages. It always worked very well, but lately, the requests are redirected to the google translate. The url of the referred redirection is something like http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://mywebsite.com. Do you have any idea why is this happening? I would appreciate a tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

They have an automatic system to catch sites that abuse their system. My site was caught on that, but this time was a mistake. They get me a manual override on their system to prevent future redirections.

Best regards

Comment: How were you able to contact them? I am having the same issue and I can't seem to find a place to report this problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry Yosep! I just saw this message now (I'm new at Stackoverflow, so i'm a dumb user, yet. Forgive me). I really hope you got your problem solved by now, however I'll answer your question. You may contact them at contact@translateth.is. They don't retrieve a quick answer but at least they answer.